# сохранить статистику по курсу обучения в файл на сервер

Tags: php, laravel, файлы

В системе дистанционного обучения, осуществляется сбор статистических данных о прохождении тестов пользователями. Статистика, на данный момент, выводится одной общей таблицей.

```
/** Формирование статистики **/
    $data = [];
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $id = $user->id;
        $data[$id] = [
            'fio' => $user->last_name.' '.$user->first_name.' '.$user->second_name,
        ];
        /** Входная статистика */
        $stat = Result::whereRaw('user_id = '.$id.' and exam_id = '.$enter_exam->id)->latest()->first();
        $data = $this->addStat($stat, $data, $id, 'course', 'enter');
        /** Заключительная статистика */
        $stat = Result::whereRaw('user_id = '.$id.' and exam_id = '.$finish_exam->id)->latest()->first();
        $data = $this->addStat($stat, $data, $id, 'course', 'finish');
        /** Статистика по Лекциям */
        if(count($lectures)) {
            foreach($lectures as $lecture) {
                $exam = $lecture->exam()->firstOrFail();
                $stat = Result::whereRaw('user_id = '.$id.' and exam_id = '.$exam->id)->latest()->first();
                $data = $this->addStat($stat, $data, $id, 'lectures', $lecture->slug);
            }
        } else {
            $data[$id]['lectures'] = null;
        }
```

Требуется, по окончании курса, сохранить данные статистики в файл и разместить его на сервере, для дальнейшего скачивания администратором при необходимости.

Comment: Вопрос не полный. В каком формате сохранить? а что конкретно не получается ? Вы не знаете как сохранить данные в файл ?

Comment: @Exileed Да, верно, я не понимаю каким образом сохранить полученные данные. Сохранить в любом формате, лишь бы администратор смог скачать получившуюся табличку и в дальнейшем распечатать при необходимости. Я не понимаю каким образом: Полученные данные статистики->Сохранение в файл->Сохранение на сервер и вывод в админку

Comment: Отвечу ответом. суда не поместилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм примерно таков

1. Взять данные с БД.
2. Сохранить в файл вывод.

Можно сделать так 
Настроить файл систему.

Добавить в  `config/filesystems.php`

```
'disks' => [
  'csv' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path().'/csv',
  ],
],
```

И сохранять данные в файл таким способом

```
Storage::disk('csv')->put('file.csv', $content);
$content = Storage::disk('csv')->get('file.csv');
```

Читать тоже через `Storage`

3. Сделать роутер который id читает это файл и отдает клиенту. (а лучше по рамдомной строчке, дабы исключить перебор)